# How do I create a redirect from two different urls redirect to just one URL? (see code below)

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, vbscript

I want to create a redirect from two different urls redirect to just one URL. I hope this question has a simple answer, I've actually provided the sample code I'm using below & just wanted to know if I could add another URL to the code below maybe using an "else if" statement....Thanks for your help

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
servername = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
if trim(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")) = "levi.com" or 
trim(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")) = "levis.com" then

url = "http://www.timoloud.com/"
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", url
Response.End
end if
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
function redirect() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.levi.com/timoloud.com';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="redirect();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be more effectively (and more efficiently) done from the server-side?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Select Case` statement may be easier to doing this.

```
Select Case Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
    Case "levi.com", "levis.com", "other.com", "another.com"
        url = "http://www.timoloud.com/"
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
        Response.AddHeader "Location", url
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear to me but i suppose you want something like this

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %> 
<% 
servername = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
redirectedUrls = "/levi.com/levis.com/"
if instr(redirectedUrls,"/" & servername & "/") then
  url = "http://www.timoloud.com/" 
  Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently" 
  Response.AddHeader "Location", url 
  Response.End 
end if 
%> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script language="Javascript"> 
  function redirect() { 
    window.location.href = 'http://www.<%=servername%>/timoloud.com'; 
  } 
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="redirect();"> 
</body> 
</html>
```